# Android Collections.compare() change criteria

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am developing a game for android and I save the scores in a text file of the form "100&playername1,93&playername1,1950&playername2" etc. i.e. it is totally unordered.

Now I am trying to make a high score interface and I am aware that to sort the scores I should use `String.split(",")` followed by `String.split("&")[0]` to get the scores and put these in an ArrayList and then call `Collections.compare(list)`. However once I have done that I then have no way of finding the names associated with the score.

Could anyone help me with this please. I have tried sorting the whole string in between brackets (putting the phrase "100&playername1" into the array, but that can't sort according to orders of magnitude. By this I mean it would put 100 ahead of 1950.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: make a comparable class 'Highscore'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a class called `UsernameScorePair`. Once you have split the scores and the usernames, put them in pairs (one for each "score&username").

For example, this class definition could work:

public class UsernameScorePair {

```
    private String name;
    private int score;

    public UsernameScorePair(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

}
```

Make a class called `UsernameScorePairComparator` that implements [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

In the `compare(Object o1, Object o2)` method, cast the Objects to UsernameScorePairs and compare the scores. For example:

```
public class UsernameScorePairComparator {

    public UsernameScorePairComparator() {
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        UsernameScorePair usp1 = (UsernameScorePair)o1;
        UsernameScorePair usp2 = (UsernameScorePair)o2;

        return usp1.getScore() - usp2.getScore();
    }
}
```

Then use `Collections.sort` like this:

`Collections.sort(listofpairs, new UsernameScorePairComparator())`

I don't remember if it sorts in ascending order or descending order. If it's ascending order, then just change `return usp1.getScore() - usp2.getScore();` to `return usp2.getScore() - usp1.getScore();`

**EDIT**

A `Comparator` basically compares two objects. In its `compareTo` method, it returns a negative value if the first is less than the second, a positive one if the first is greater than the second, and zero if they are both equal.

You can implement a `Comparator` (as I just did) to suit your needs. Then, using that `Comparator`, you can use standard API methods such as `Collections.sort()`.

I hope this works!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! OK I've only just started out and you're going to have to bear with me. When you say make the UsernameScorePair class, does this class have private variables which are score and name? And I have never even heard of Comparators - tried googling them but all I found is a lot of confusing syntax, could you point me the right way please.

Answer (score 0):

A way is to have a custom object (call it `Score`) that contains the score and the player. Then put your scores in a list of `Score`, with a custom comparator that compares on scores.

```
final String wholeString = "100&playername1,93&playername1,1950&playername2";

final List<Score> scoresForPlayers = new ArrayList<Score>();
final String[] scores = wholeString.split(",");
for (String score : scores) {
    final String[] split = score.split("&");
    scoresForPlayers.add(new Score(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), split[1]));
}
Collections.sort(scoresForPlayers, new Comparator<Score>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Score o1, Score o2) {
        return o1.score.compareTo(o2.score);
    }
});

class Score {
    private final Integer score;
    private final String player;

    public Score(Integer score, String player) {
        this.score = score;
        this.player = player;
    }
}
```

Comment: so far I like this answer the most, looks the quickest to implement. I'll give it a try and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the elements and create a new Player for each String like so:

```
public class Player implements Comparable<Player>{

private int mScore;

private final String mName;

public Player(final int score, final String name) {
    mScore = score;
    mName = name;
}

public void setScore(final int score) {
    mScore = score;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Player other) {
    return mScore - other.mScore;
}

}
```

Now you just need to call `Collections.sort(List<Player>);` And you can even make the Player class implement the `Serializable` interface:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Player implements Comparable<Player>, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8257815475849584162L;

private int mScore;

private final String mName;

public Player(final int score, final String name) {
    mScore = score;
    mName = name;
}

public void setScore(final int score) {
    mScore = score;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Player other) {
    return mScore - other.mScore;
}

    readObject(){...}
    writeObject(){...}

 }
```